# Conditional or unconditional request via HTTPS to another subdomain?

Tags: caching, browser, ssl, subdomain

My server deliver page via `HTTPS` (as well as any resource on the page). The page by itself comes from main domain: `domain.com`, while other resources such as images or css comes from the following subdomains:
`img.domain.com` and `css.domain.com` respectively. Images and css resources have Cache-Control in response headers, i.e. they should be cached.

The question is why the browser requests images and css resources each time I open the page?

On other hand, if all resources comes from the same domain - everything is taken from the cache? Why it is so? And it looks like this behavior is not the same in different browsers: in some browsers I see conditional requests while in others - unconditional. Is there any standard for such case?

Answer (score 0):

Is Cache-Control set to public for the resources from the alternative domains?

This is a bit of an ancient (2009) article that might help - http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/01/15/https-performance-tuning/

I'd also consider whether you want to serve the CSS from a separate host...

- the browsers going to have to do a DNS lookup, and open up a new TCP connection
- if you used the same host DNS lookup goes away, connection overhead may go away (IE9, Chrome speculatively open a second connection), but you get the overhead of the HTTPS negotiation back.

I don't know the right answer without measuring but it's worth thinking about.

Comment: Yes, I've tried Cache-Control: public, but it has no effect. I don't think there will be additional HTTPS negotiation as browsers cache SSL sessions.